Applied condition not removing in Laravel darryldecode cart
I'm using Laravel 8 and using Darryldecode Package

Reference : https://packagist.org/packages/darryldecode/cart

to apply discount i'm using this method
  $couponExists=Coupon::where('code',$couponcode)->first();
        if($couponExists)
        {
            if($couponExists->type=='fixed')
            {  
                $condition2 = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                    'name' => 'FIXED',
                    'type' => $couponcode,
                    'target' => 'total', 
                    'value' => $couponExists->value,
                    'order' => 1,
                    'description' => 'Fixed coupon',
                    'more_data' => 'Fixed coupon'
                ));
                \Cart::condition($condition2);

                if (auth()->guard('web')->check()) {
                    $userID = auth()->guard('web')->id();
                    \Cart::session($userID)->condition($condition2);
                }
                else
                {
                    \Cart::session('token')->condition($condition2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $condition = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                    'name' => 'PERCENT',
                    'type' => $couponcode,
                    'target' => 'total', 
                    'value' => '15%',
                    'attributes' => array( 
                    'description' => 'Percentage coupon',
                    'more_data' => 'Percentage coupon'
                    )
                ));

                if (auth()->guard('web')->check()) {
                    $userID = auth()->guard('web')->id();
                    \Cart::session($userID)->condition($condition);
                }
                else
                {
                    \Cart::session('token')->condition($condition);
                }

            }
        }

and it is applied also but now i'm trying to remove that condition
 $cartConditions = \Cart::getConditions();
        if(count($cartConditions) > 0)
        {
            foreach($cartConditions as $condition)
            {
                $targetName=$condition->getName(); 
                $targetConditions=$condition->getTarget();
                $targetType=$condition->getType();
                \Cart::removeCartCondition($targetName);
                \Cart::removeConditionsByType($targetType);                }
                \Cart::clearCartConditions();
        }

but the discount i applied is not getting removed through this code.
Any solution to fix this issue.
Thanks
